# Arranging properly the results of two for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, scrapy, yield

So as you'll see from the code below, I'm scraping some info with Scrapy. Everything works fine, I'm just not happy the way the scraped data is stored. With the current code, I get results as a column of 'X' and a column of 'Y' side by side (which is fine), but the results for 'U' show up as a row as it is run from a 2nd loop. So what I would like, is to have the scraped data in three columns side by side: X / Y / U. Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance!

```
def parse(self, response):
    U = []
    for l in response.css('div.property-info-wrapper'):
        yield {
            'X': l.css('span.info-price::text').extract_first(),
            'Y': l.css('li::text').extract_first(),
        }

    for i in response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="property-info-location ellipsis-element-control"]/text()').extract():
        U.append(i)
    yield {'U':U}
```

Comment: can you post a minimal and testable html fragment containing all the needed items?

Comment: Hi, the issue got fixed but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.zip_longest` to zip both results together and yield them based on their Truth value <sup>*</sup>.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def parse(self, response):
    locations = response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="property-info-location ellipsis-element-control"]/text()').extract()
    css = response.css('div.property-info-wrapper')

    for loc, c in zip_longest(css, locations):
        if loc:
            yield {
                'X': loc.css('span.info-price::text').extract_first(),
                'Y': loc.css('li::text').extract_first(),
            }
        if c:
            yield {'U': c}  # since spider needs to return dict
```

---

<sub>*  [itertools.zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=None)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):
Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables. If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is exhausted.</sub>

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I made a small mistake in the initial code, 'locations' was intended to be 'U'. Don't know if that makes any difference in your answer.

Comment: @fg42 Yeah I guessed that. I doesn't make any difference tho.

Comment: I'm getting this error from scrapy: "Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'str'". X & Y are scraped correctly though.

Comment: @fg42 I think that's because of `yield c` you can change it to `{'U': c}` or smth.

Comment: okay it does work. Weirdly I get a lot of blank cells but I can remove them easily so that's not really an issue because all the data is scraped. Many thanks!

Comment: @fg42 The blank cells are not because of `zip_longest` because as I said we filter out the None values before yielding.